# Wordpress logout is redirecting my users to pop up

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page for login on my site. Login is working well, but whenever my users click logout it direct the users to a popup requesting for username and password. Check image below. How can I let my users bypass that popup login screen. [image]

Comment: A little more context will help. By the sounds of it, they are not required to log in to use the site however the module or process you have in place forces that action.

Comment: @Mech whenever the user input admin as username and admin as password it will go successfully.

Comment: Logout redirects the user to example.com/wp-login.php?action=logout&_wpnonce but it requires a default wordpress default username and password in to logout.

Comment: This isn't the default login page or behaviour of WP so you have custom code somewhere that's doing this. Without being able to see that code, we have no idea what is happening or why it's doing this. You need to find out more about what is causing this (your theme? a plugin? code you added yourself?), and let us know the debugging details so that we have enough information to be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your directory is password protected, this isn't default Wordpress login page.
Go to your cPanel > Directory Privacy > check if the password is set there and remove it.